# jQuery EasyTabs: All Content Shows On Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm using the jQuery EasyTabs plugin. I have a web page with two tabs working pretty well. However, when the page containing the tab code loads, for a brief moment both tabs' panel contents (not the tabs themselves) are visible. It's only for a moment, then the second tab's panel content is hidden, and things work as they should. Super annoying.

Any attempts I've made to hide or delay these content from being shown using jQuery or DOM calls have not been successful. Here's the call I make, whose code is loaded just above the HTML of the tabs and panels.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#tab-container').easytabs();
  });
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion, as a workaround and without being able to actually see the problem, is to initially hide the offending elements with CSS then show them after `easytabs()` has been called. The problem is likely because there is a tiny delay between the elements loading and the jQuery call.

So `#tab-container { display: hidden };` then:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#tab-container').easytabs();
  $('#tab-container').show();
});
```